# about facebook share og:url

Tags: share, facebook-sharer

now 
I have put  meta tag  og:url 、 og:image to my page head.

I have three server environment（ dev server（1） 、preview server（1） and live server（6））.

when i put dev url  and preview url  into facebook input box (or http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug )  there can get my meta info.

but when i put my live url to input box( or http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) there
is nothing for me.

I must be crazy about this.
is somebody can help me. thx.

Answer (score 0):

What is your live url?  Maybe there's something not configured on the webserver correctly.

Comment: It's taken over 170 seconds and still no information from that URL.  I think Facebook is timing out getting information from your URL, forcing Facebook to use an older cached version of the information.  Try removing all html other than just the facebook stuff to see if it's a webserver issue, or a content issue.

Comment: you are right。 i test when it only have facebook meta ,it can share success  look this http://www.goyeah.com/test_facebook/test_yeahtv_only_og.php

Comment: but i must stay the contents in my page, could you tell me how can i do ? thx

Comment: Since the smaller page load up quickly, it doesn't look like a server issue (unless one in the cluster is behaving differently than the others). Since the test works well, start adding content one item at a time and keep checking load times until you find the item (or group of items) causing the extra extra long load time.

Comment: Awesome, that works much better.  I check the debugger tool and it is now showing the image and all the meta data.    http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work